# Jquery scrollLeft hover

Tags: jquery

How do i alter the code below so that the div scroll's left continously on hover?  At the moment i have it at `120px`, which causes me having to keep putting my mouse over the next-button again everytime the scrolling stops.  I want the div to scrollLeft at a slow speed if the mouse is over the next-button. Here is the JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mdanz/nCCRy/14/

```
$(function() {

$('#next-button').hover(function() {
    $('#display-container').animate({
        'scrollLeft': '+=120px'
    }, '500');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval.

```
$(function() {

   var timeoutID = null;

   $('#next-button').hover(function() {
       if(timeoutID == null) {
            timeoutID = window.setInterval(startAnimate, 2000); 
       }
   });

   $("#next-button").mouseout(function() {
       window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
       timeoutID = null; 
   });
});

function startAnimate() {
    $('#display-container').animate({
        'scrollLeft': '+=120px'
    }, '500');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution for your problem. 
Here's the code :

```
$('#next-button').hover(function () {
    $('#display-container').each(function () {
        var item = $(this)[0];
        $(this).animate({ scrollLeft: item.scrollWidth }, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

already answered in: [Scroll on hover, click for speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188952/scroll-on-hover-click-for-speed)

Just change it to scrollLeft instead of scrollTop. Hint: to have smoother scroll effect set a smaller interval time.

```js
var interval;
var count;

$('.yourButton').on('mouseover', function() {
    var div = $('.yourScrollElementBox');

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      count = count || 1;
      var pos = div.scrollLeft();
      div.scrollLeft(pos + count);
    }, 10);
  }).on('mouseout', function() {
    // Uncomment this line if you want to reset the speed on out
    // count = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
```