# What is the lowest jQuery speed that can be set?

Tags: jquery

I am using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count;
    var interval;
    $("#hoverscroll").on('mouseover', function() {
       var div = $('body');
       interval = setInterval(function(){
        count = count || 1;
        var pos = div.scrollTop();
        div.scrollTop(pos + count);
        }, 100);
    }).click(function() {
        count < 6 && count++;
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        // Uncomment this line if you want to reset the speed on out
        // count = 0;
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

From here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189355/1063287

which has a jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcsb6/

**Question**

What is the lowest speed I can set this?

When I change `100` to `25` it speeds up.

Comment: Sure speed is up) interval must be upping for slow speed. Set `interval` about 500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19475901/447356) that part of the code is not jQuery, setInterval is native JavaScript method. (See [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and [Microsoft documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536749(v=vs.85).aspx))

That method accepts a "delay" argument, telling how many milliseconds to wait between each execution.

To have the code run slower, just give higher value. What you currently have is 100 milliseconds, meaning the code inside the given function will execute 10 times in a second. So changing the 100 to 1000 will make it execute once every second, making it slower.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with jQuery.

The minimum delay value you can use with `setInterval` varies from browser to browser. The draft spec [recommends a minimum of `4`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers) (a delay of 4ms). Not all browsers do that. You can safely use `0` to get the browser's minimum value.

> What is the lowest speed I can set this?

The lowest speed would be the highest delay, a greater delay slows things down. I'm not aware of a *maximum* value limit on `setInterval`. I've seen people use five *minutes* (`300000`).

Comment: I think OP wants slower, not faster.